# How to add nofollow and noindex in php code?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags

This is my code, how can I add nofollow and noindex on social links?

```
<?= wp_nav_menu([
                'menu' => 'social_links',
                'menu_class' => 'social-links',
                'container' => false,
                'echo' => false,
                'depth' => 1,
                'items_wrap' => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                'item_spacing' => 'discard',
                'link_before' => '',
                'link_after' => '',
            ]) . "\n" ?>
```

Comment: you may need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry mate, i didnt have time to wrote correctly)

Comment: Feedback: I have downvoted for not having time to write correctly.

Comment: thx mate, i appreciate it))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this & it will work fine.

```
header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a special HTML  tag to tell robots not to index the content of a page, and/or not scan it for links to follow.

For Example :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
(…)
</head>
<body>(…)</body>
</html>
```